# adding an onload event listener to IE extension

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, bho

how can i add an onload event listener to an IE extension?I want the extension to detect onload event and accordingly execute the code on detecting the event.How can that be done?I have used this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735854(v=vs.85).aspx#IEAddOnsToolbars_topic2 but i don't know how can i attach an event listener.I am new to extensions, any help would be highly appreciated.thanks

Comment: Are you still waiting responses?

Comment: yes any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you try the below
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995136/ie-extension-to-inject-javascript-in-the-webpage/22143060#22143060